My PC stopped recognizing my second screen from one day to the next
Yesterday I was using my PC to study like a normal day, and today I turned it back on and it doesn't recognize my second screen.
My main screen is connected via HDMI and my secondary screen via VGA, I tried connecting it via DVI but it doesn't work either. I put a VGA to HDMI adapter on my secondary screen and disconnecting my main screen works.
I have the theory that it only works when connecting the monitors via HDMI but I'm sure it's not a hardware problem since yesterday it worked perfectly and I didn't have any energy problems or anything like that.
Can someone help me and tell me if it's necessary to reset some driver or something similar?
